# How should I attend the jar library for GCM server?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

[While following the instructions to setup a cloud messaging backend for an android app](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend), I came across a section that reads "Open Android SDK Manager and choose Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. This creates a gcm directory under YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/gcm-server/dist subdirectory which has the gcm-server.jar file."

However, attempting to download the library from the Android SDK Manager and some gratuitous amounts of research reveals that the Google Cloud messaging libraries for Android have been deprecated.

I'm still thinking that I need the gcm-server.jar for the backend however. What is the preferred way now of adding the gcm-server.jar to my project, or at least, what is the preferred way of adding the GCM functionality to my backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gcm-server.jar` has not been deprecated. Only the client side jar was deprecated (`gcm.jar`). `gcm-server.jar` makes it easier to send GCM messages from a java server, but you don't have to use it. You can write your own code for building the HTTP requests, posting them to the GCM server and parsing the response.

If you decide to use the jar, simply include it in your build path.